# What is TaosAdapter?

Tags: connector, tdengine

Recently, I found that TaosAdapter has been shows up in TDengine github repository as an individual module, the readme file only lists multiple functionalities which indict its a type of connector. However, I didn't find any resource or documentation about what is TaosApapter and what the reason this connector was created? Can anyone find some documentations for me or give me a simplify general statement for TaosAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

TaosAdapter is a TDengine’s companion tool and is a bridge/adapter between TDengine cluster and application. You can find the answer in https://github.com/taosdata/taosadapter#readme